# How to keep service alive in android kitkat?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Hello friends i have searched a lot but not find the change in service the Google have done I need to keep my service alive.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
    }
```

but it not restarting the service in android 4.4.2 any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this for Android kitkat because they are clearing the process from the background.

```
 @Override
        public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
         Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    this.getClass());
            restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
            PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                    getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000, restartServicePI);

        }
```